# The question about elementary equivalence of free products

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, model-theory, universal-algebra, algebraic-systems

Let $A,B,C,D$ be algebraic systems and $A$ and $B$ be elementary equivalent as well as $C$ and $D$. Are free products of $A,C$ and $B,D$ elementary equivalent if

1. $A,B,C,D$ are groups, or
2. $A,B,C,D$ are Lie algebras?

If one of this problem (or both) has  already been solved, it would be nice to get a reference to the corresponding paper(s).

Comment: I assume you already know this, but the answer is positive for direct (Cartesian) products of arbitrary first-order structures.

Comment: If the structures are $\omega$-saturated then you should be able to argue with Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games that the resulting free products are elementarily equivalent. This is only non-trivial if the structures are uncountable, though.

Comment: I guess it's meant universal algebraic systems (with only laws, no relations) otherwise I don't see how to define the free products.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Do you have a reference? I'm aware of a quite indirect proof, making use of ultraproducts and absoluteness.

Comment: @YCor Mostowski, *On direct products of theories*, Journal of Symbolic Logic 17 (1952), 1–31. The Feferman–Vaught theorem is a considerable generalization: Feferman, Vaught, *The first order properties of  products of algebraic systems*, Fundamenta Mathematicae 47 (1959), 57–103.

Answer (score 5):

For free products of groups, this is Theorem 7.1 of Zlil Sela's preprint [Diophantine geometry over groups X: the elementary theory of free products of groups](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zlil/prodl.pdf).